# How can i get the last match of the loop over the structure

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

i am running a loop :

```
<cfset rulecounter = 1>
<cfloop collection="#mystucts#" index="key">

<cfif rulecounter neq thevaluewhere it should match>
OR
</cfif>
<cfset rulecounter = rulecounter + 1>
</cfloop>
```

so trying to do a match here if it is the last item in struct, do not add `OR`, else keep adding `OR`

Comment: Is this supposed to end up as OR chain for sql WHERE?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you put more than the word 'or' in the allocated space.

Comment: Thanks fo the link, but actually solved it with the counter inside the loop and then comparing the value of the counter

Comment: I don't think this was a duplicate of the other question and have voted to reopen the question.  If it is reopened, I invite the OP to post his solution as an answer.